# Objective-C - C style string allocation leak?

Tags: objective-c, string, memory, memory-leaks

I have a very simple app. From the main screen I launch a new view ("learn view") that displays an image and a label. on the learn view there is a menu button and a next button. When the user taps the next button, the view updates the image and the label from char * array of C strings. However, when I do this, the instruments allocations shows a forever growing number of allocations that are not reduced when the view is destroyed by clicking the menu button. If I just display the learn view then click menu there is no problem, the allocations go up and then go back down to the prior level, but if I click next updating the label.text, then allocations are made that are not recovered. Instruments reports no leaks. here are relevant code snippets:

LearnVC.h

```
@interface LearnVC : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    IBOutlet UILabel *labelView1;
    NSInteger page;

}
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *labelView1;

@property NSInteger page;

- (IBAction)handleNext;
- (IBAction) gotoMenu;

@end
```

LearnVC.m

```
#import ...

char *states[] { "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", ... };
#define maxStates 50

@implementation LearnVC

@synthesize ...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

      NSString *tstring;
      self.page = 0;


      //test!!!!
      tstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:states[self.page] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      labelView1.text = tstring;
      [tstring release];

      [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (IBAction) handleNext {

      NSString *tstring;
      self.page++;
      if (self.page > maxStates-1) {
           self.page = 0;
      }

      //test!!!!
      tstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:states[self.page] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      labelView1.text = tstring;
      [tstring release];

}

- (void)dealloc
{

      [imageView release];
      [labelView1 release];
      [super dealloc];

}
```

This seems to occur anytime I update a view without removing (deallocating) it and re-adding it. Is there something with old C arrays that don't copy/release properly. Or some issue with UILabel.text properties that don't release memory?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks beforehand, Neal

I converted it to use NSArray -

I added this to the .h file

```
NSArray *statesArray;
```

and
    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *statesArray;

then in the .m file

in viewDidLoad

```
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alabama", @"Montgomery",
                    @"Alaska", @"Juneau" ,..., nil];

self.statesArray = objects;

//I assume that since I didn't init it, I don't need to release objects.

labelView1.text = [self.statesArray objectAtIndex:self.page];in dealloc

[statesArray release];
```

Then in my handleNext

```
labelView1.text = [self.statesArray objectAtIndex:self.page];
```

I run through the entire array, exit, reload, ect. and the allocations climb the first time through but stop climbing after I've been through the list once.  This was not the case with the char * array, there must be something else going on, oh well, I'll just have to shed my old C ways and stick to NS/UI classes.

This seems to have solved it.  Now I'll work on the image loads and see if the it works the same.

Comment: I have a feeling you are omitting some important pieces of code. In particular, what are you doing with your labelView1 object? I see you are using its ivar (circumventing release mechanics). Please post code showing what you are doing with labelView1.

Comment: I suspect that you may just be seeing "overhead".  Sometimes the system decides, eg, to permanently allocate short strings and reuse them, rather than freeing them on `release`.

Comment: @Perception, the labelView1 text property is retained like any other, and so long as labelView1 is eventually released, so should the text property.

Comment: Besides all the previous comments, there's really no good reason to be using a C array of C-strings here.  All you're doing is asking for trouble.  Use an NSArray of NSStrings.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - if you say so then it must be. There's no leak I can see in the code you posted so you must be fine.

Comment: This really is the only code that does anything with labelView1.  It's linked in interface builder, and released in the dealloc method.  I would think it was just caching, but I run through the whole list and then start over, and it still goes up, and the allocations don't drop when I exit the view.  Its as if it is not releasing the text property upon the assignment of the next text.  When I have 2 labels and an image that is changed the same way, it fills up memory and crashes.  I'll try an NSArray of NSStrings and report.

Comment: There may actually be a bug in initWithCString or some such -- such bugs are not unheard of.  But it's easier and more straight-forward to, as suggesgted, use the NSArray of NSStrings (or just an array of NSStrings, if you properly release them in dealloc).  (Hint, to create the NSArray of NSStrings use a long initial string with delimiters and use stringsSeparatedByString to create the array.  Do this once in init.)

Comment: @nwestwood -- Have you placed a breakpoint in dealloc to make sure it's getting called??  Maybe the whole controller is over-retained.

Comment: Somewhat offtopic: it's easier to use initWithUTF8String.

Answer (score 2):

The `initWithCString:encoding:` method may make an internal copy of the C string you pass in, but is not guaranteed to free the copy during deallocation. Since the C strings you're passing are constant, and therefore can never be freed, you can instead use `initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone:` to avoid creating the extra copies. For example:

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:someCString
                                             length:strlen(someCString)
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                       freeWhenDone:NO];
```

Comment: I'm sure it's something like that, although classes should be smart enough to handle it.  I'll try that next time I have to use c-strings.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the system does a lot of caching, it acts like each control may cache the text it has used.  I found that if I ran through the series a couple of times, then then allocations stopped rising, as if it had cached all it was going to. Allocations did not go down to the starting point when exiting learn view, but subsequent runs did not add anymore.